# ui-router: Difference between onEnter and onStart?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm switching to new version of **ui-router** (1.0.0-alpha.5) and trying to figure out where to use **onEnter** hook and where **onStart**:

```
$transitions.onStart()
```

and

```
$transitions.onEnter()
```

before it was just event *$stateChangeStart*

Comment: @developer033, e4c5, Ismail RBOUH, vgoff, DeanOC updated the question, hope now it's clear

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how [the doc](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/feature-1.0/index.html) describes the transition lifecycle hooks execution order:

```
onBefore
onStart/onInvalid
onEnter (for individual states)
onSuccess
onError
```

... but it seems to be a little bit outdated (I'll get back to that later). Still, it clearly shows that `onEnter` hooks are about *entering a state*, and `onStart` hooks are about *starting a Transition between states*.

Actually, that key difference is described quite well in [the hook doc pages](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/feature-1.0/interfaces/transition.ihookregistry.html):

> `onStart` hooks are invoked asynchronously, in priority order, when the
>   Transition starts running. **At this point, the Transition has not
>   exited nor entered any states yet.**
>
> `onEnter` hooks are invoked asynchronously, in priority order, when
>   the Transition is entering a state. States are entered after the
>   `onRetain` hooks.

`onStart` hook seems to be a good place to validate a transition - for example, to check whether or not a user is authenticated. Here's a code example given in that doc:

```
$transitions.onStart( { to: 'auth.*' }, function(MyAuthService, $state) {
  // If the user is not authenticated
  if (!MyAuthService.isAuthenticated()) {

    // Then return a promise for a successful login.
    // The transition will wait for this promise to settle
    return MyAuthService.authenticate().catch(function() {

      // Redirect to a state that we know doesn't require auth.
      return $state.target("guest");
    });
  }
});
```

---

Judging from that last page, the order actually is:

```
onBefore - Transition is about to start; one can register other hooks here "on-the-fly"
onStart  - Transition starts running
onExit   - Transition is exiting a state
onRetain - Transition retains a state
onEnter  - Transition is entering a state 
onFinish - Transition is about to be completed, all states are entered and exited

onSuccess/onError - Transition is completed (either successfully or not)
```

NB: all but the last two hooks can modify the transition - change the target state etc. `onSuccess` and `onError` are fired post factum: the transition is over.